# MVC4 solution adding a new project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `MVC4` project which is going to be a large system, I want to split the database management into its own project so in my solution I will have `MyMVC4` and `MyMVC4_Data`

I will add `MyMVC4_Data` as a reference to the main `MyMVC4` project. I believe there will be multiple projects in the future so splitting the data makes sense.

My question is, what sort of project template will be sufficient for the database stuff, all it will have is `Linq` and manager classes for each table to insert delete etc. I don't think it would be necessary to include a new MVC4 project as the overheads will be too big for what is needed. The project must be referable by the main project

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a [Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e6w3tyx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) project. From the docs:

> You can use the Class Library template to quickly create reusable classes and components that can be shared with other projects.

Comment: +1 and just add the needed references manually. No sense to have another MVC project